# Is it possible to load JSON data in Wordpress without using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, wordpress

So, I'm diving head first into something I have little knowledge about; Wordpress and using AngularJS to display custom data in a custom page within a theme. Most of what I have just stated, I've been able to find proper documentation on how to make it work, however, all of it references the JSON gathering using AJAX. Is it possible to pull JSON data from WP using a bootstrap (not sure if this is the correct term) method?

For example, as soon as the page loads, the `<head>` would contain all of the necessary JSON data available to the application without having to make an AJAX request to get it:

```
<head>    
    <script>
       var jsonData = {
          "prop" : "value"
       }
    </script>
</head>
```

So far I've learned that WP has a JSON REST API available to display data in JSON, however, can it be used as it is displayed above as opposed to using an HTTP request to get the data and assign it to an Angular model?

Comment: without ajax, load external data? not possible....

Comment: Wait ... what? That's disappointing... I've done applications using Angular in .NET environments before and the developer I was working with was able to do this with a .NET CMS by gathering data from the db, converting it into a JSON object and presenting it as a global var as soon as the application loaded.. Nothing like this is possible with WP???

Comment: Yes, you could create a global variable, sure.

Comment: you can, just echo the code you have above into your page and you will have a js object to work with. The only thing is its now static (you cant query the db again without ajax until you refresh the page)

Comment: It's definitely possible. You can query the database in php and then add the data to the page as you have done above. It's not recommended though as it won't be a SPA if you are doing this as you would normally have static views and perform ajax queries to fetch data.

Comment: Phew, ok, got worried there for a second. Yep, I'm actually going for the static view approach because all I need is to leverage the power of angular to update the view as certain selections from the model are made. Afterwards, AJAX will definitely be involved, but I see no reason why I have to load the app, then make an AJAX request to fetch the initial data.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal not possible? what about sockets?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know about that, never heared...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets

Comment: hmmm, it's about/like nodejs, will learn later, thanks....